# How to identify cells in Column A that contain any of the values in Column B

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

First off, I'm not that advanced of an Excel user. I'm certain Excel can do what I'm about to ask, but I've yet to find a way in any of my attempts or searches.

My question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315551/find-if-value-in-column-a-contains-value-from-column-b except that A) the answers there didn't work for me, and B) even if it did, it's not quite the correct output I need.

Basically, I have 2 columns. Column A contains URLs (16388 rows). Column B contains URL slugs (202 rows).

I want to search to see if any of the values in column B are contained within any of the values of Column A. If they are, I want to return the value `TRUE` in column C.

From what I've read, `VLOOKUP` ought to work for this, but for the life of me I can't get it to work. I also tried in the answers in the link above that use `COUNTIF` and `MATCH`, but in both of those cases, all I got were `FALSE` returns, when I know that there are values in Column B that are contained in a URL in Column A.

Does that make sense?

EDIT: Both answers are providing results (thank you!), but I suspect I may not have asked the question correctly. In both of the answers, I'm getting TRUE results, but it looks like the TRUE is correlating to the slug in Column B rather than the URL in Column A. Let me put it this way:

I'll move the slugs from Column B to C so that B can be used for the TRUE responses. What I want the fomula to do is:

1. Look at URL in A1
2. Are any of the values in Column C contained within the URL in A1?
3. If yes, then return TRUE in B1. If FALSE, leave it blank.

So I will be able to see which of the URLs contain the slugs I am searching for. I apologize for not being clearer in my original ask (though I feel like it's only a slight tweak from the answers I've already been given.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `vlookup` use `match` when looking for exact values, or `. Try this in cell C1:

```
=Match(B1,A:A,0)
```

If found this'll return the row number found, if B was not n A, then it'll return an error.

So then you can take it a step further and say this:

```
=If(Iserror(Match(B1,A:A,0)),"This B Is Not Found In Column A","This B is in Column A")
or
=If(Iserror(Match(B1,A:A,0)),"False","True")
```

Finally note that all of the match code above is for finding an exact match.
If you want to check if B is ANYWHERE within A, you need to put `*` wildcards on each side of it like this:

```
=If(Iserror(Match("*"&B1&"*",A:A,0)),"False","True")
```

Comment: So I modified your first answer to utilize the wildcards, so it read:=MATCH("*"&B1&"*",A:A,0), and that worked like a champ! It turns out I'm looking for a somewhat different output (see my edit to the original question), but I'm definitely saving this answer as well as this output is extremely useful to me. Thanks! :)

Comment: Ah, I'm glad all the typing with my answer proved useful so that you could modify it the way you needed!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following formula, returning True if match is found and false otherwise?

```
=not(isna(match("*"&b1&"*",A:A,0)))
```

Comment: That did work, but it was the right answer to the wrong question (I've made an edit to the original post to try to clarify). Thank you for your help. It always better when the Asker is clear on what they want :)