# How to identify if a cell contains any of the values in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

My question is the opposite (inverse?) of [How to identify cells in Column A that contain any of the values in Column B](https://superuser.com/questions/486710/how-to-identify-cells-in-column-a-that-contain-any-of-the-values-in-column-b). Specifically:

I have a list of 19,000 first names and 10,000 passwords. I'm trying to identify the passwords that contain first names.

For example, the passwords "mary" and "1mary!" should both return True.

With this formula, only exact matches were marked True:

```
=If(Iserror(Match("*"&B1&"*",A:A,0)),"False","True")
```

I found myself wanting to do the following, but it didn't work:

```
=If(Iserror(Match(B1,"*"&A:A&"*",0)),"False","True")
```

[where B1 is the password and A:A is the list of names].

Comment: Next time please write about your environment, you have much better chance to get useful answers if we can see that not only from your tags. Secondary, your question has imho its place on the stackoverflow and on superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.  Take what you tried, and switch the order or the parameters:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*"&A:A&"*",B1,0)), "False", "True")
```

Now limit (bound) it to the actual list of names, rather than the entire `A` column:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*"&A$1:A$19000&"*",B1,0)), "False", "True")
```

and add an `AND()` function:

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(MATCH("*"&A$1:A$19000&"*",B1,0))), "False", "True")
```

and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end,
so it becomes an *array formula* and displays with curly braces:

```
{=IF(AND(ISERROR(MATCH("*"&A$1:A$19000&"*",B1,0))), "False", "True")}
```

and drag/fill.

P.S. Unless you really *really* want to generate those strings
(or you really want to generate other strings, e.g., “bad” and “good”),
you can simplify to:

```
=NOT(AND(ISERROR(MATCH("*"&A$1:A$19000&"*",B1,0))))
```

<sup>(I wrote this before I saw Excellll’s answer.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FIND` instead of `MATCH` in an array formula. `FIND` returns the character number where your search term is found or an error if it is not found. Use the following.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISERROR(FIND($A$1:$A$19000,B1)))*1)>0
```

The `SUMPRODUCT` is there to make this work like an array function without requiring any special entry method.

Note: You need the exact range of names in the formula for this to work right. If that's going to be a problem, you can use the following instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(A:A,B1)))*1,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))*1)>0
```