# How do I set up a conditional formula with multiple criteria?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-statements

I recently needed to find matches occurring anywhere within a column.  This article here

[**How to identify cells in Column A that contain any of the values in Column B**](https://superuser.com/questions/486710/how-to-identify-cells-in-column-a-that-contain-any-of-the-values-in-column-b)

gave me exactly what I needed to execute this task.  Later, I discovered that I needed to do that, plus add additional criteria from a separate column.  I have been to numerous websites and have tried a number of different formulas to make this happen, but, thus far, my formula has failed every time.  To give you a visual of what I want to do, I've included an image below:

[image]

**It may help to know the following:**

- Total number of items in Column E are fewer than those in Column T (by a substantial amount).
- Cells in Column E contain a single word and no duplicates exist within that column.
- Cells in Column T contain a single word and no duplicates exist within that column.
- Cells in Column V contain either "Match," "þ" (the checked box), or are blank.
- Contents of cells in Column E may or not exist in Column T.
- "Match" indicates that cells in Column T match words in a column not shown in the image above.  In other words, it is not intended to convey a match with the contents of cells in Column E.

**Now, here is what I would like to do with these columns of information:**

- ***If the contents of a cell in E do not match any of the cells in T,*** return "V3 Only" in Column X.
- ***If the contents of a cell in E are found in Column T AND Column V contains "Match,"*** return "Match" in Column X.
- ***If the contents of a cell in E are found in Column T AND Column V contains the checked box ("þ"),*** return "þ" (the checked box) in Column X.

---

I hope this isn't too difficult to solve.  Despite my difficulty in arriving at a formula that can execute this, I have a feeling someone in this community knows how to set this up.

In case it makes a difference, I need this formula to work for Excel 2007.

Thanks in advance for anyone who knows how to do this and is willing to share it with us.

Comment: please post the formula you've used first.

Comment: Fair enough, @MátéJuhász.  Here is one of my latest attempts: =IF(EXACT(E2, T2:T2331), & IF(V2="Match","Match") OR IF(V2="þ","þ").

Comment: The formula above would just return the appropriate code for those words that are contained in Column T.  I don't even know where to begin to get it to add "V3 Only" if the word is not contained in Column T.  I thought I should work on getting one aspect of this problem solved before adding to it, but a single formula that can accomplish all three conditions listed as bullet points in my question above would be ideal.  It looks as if I may need to toy around with ISERROR, but I'm not too familiar with that function.  In fact, I'm a bit out of my depth here, so any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I also tried this: =IF(EXACT(E2, T2:T2331), "" & IF(V2="Match", "Match") OR IF(V2="þ", "þ")), which simply yields "FALSE."  I guess one of the puzzle pieces I am missing is how do I determine if one cell in one column matches any of the cells in another column.  The post I make reference to in my question above gave me a simple formula for when you are comparing one cell with an adjacent cell, not one cell with an entire column of cells.  I am guessing I need to use some sort of LOOKUP function, and if so, how and which one?

Comment: I should add that the first code I listed in this thread was _intended_ to return the appropriate code.  It doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

> If the contents of a cell in E are found in Column T AND Column V contains "Match," return "Match" in Column X.
>   If the contents of a cell in E are found in Column T AND Column V contains the checked box ("þ"), return "þ" (the checked box) in Column X.

I'd just add "if the contents of a cell in E are found in Column T AND Column V is empty, then return empty string in Column X"
And we can simplify all above to **if the contents of a cell in E are found in Column T, then return Column V in Column X**

So you don't need to use complex conditions:
`=SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(T1,$E$1:$E$19,0)),V1,"Only "&ADDRESS(ROW(V1),COLUMN(V1),4)),"0","")`

Where

- `ISNUMBER(MATCH(T1,$E$1:$E$19,0))` - checks whether value from T1 exists in column E
- `"Only "&ADDRESS(ROW(V1),COLUMN(V1),4))` - generates address of V1
- `IF(ISNUMBER(...),V1,"Only "&...)` - If T1 exists in column E, then enters V1, else "Only V1"
- `=SUBSTITUTE(IF(...),"0","")` - if V1 is blank, than formula would convert it to `0`, this converts it to `""`
- this is an array formula, so you need to insert it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I truly appreciate your efforts here, @MáteJuhász.  I should have added that "Only V3" indicates that the entire list in Column E comes from something I reference as V3 (or more precisely, "Volume 3"). So, I didn't use the ADDRESS fx. I did recently read about the ADDRESS fx, however, and seeing you use it in a formula has given me some ideas for some other things I want to do.

Comment: As for the rest of the formula, it doesn't appear to work b/c every single cell returned "Only V3" (and I know at least one should be found as a match in the other list). Perhaps, I didn't use your formula correctly. This is what I used: =SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(X1,$F$1:$F$19,0)),V1, "Only V3"), "0","") (which was entered as an array, per your instructions).

Comment: why did you included `X1` in it? `$F$1:$F$19` - is that the same range for you?? in which cell you've entered it?

Comment: Not all of my experiments made it to this thread.  One of them included doing something that involved additional columns.  It was still the correct column to use.

Answer (score -1):

After additional attempts to solve this the way I had initially envisioned it, I finally decided to yield to a more practical and less complicated way of doing the same thing.  Initially, I attempted to match the words on the shorter list to the words on the longer list (which had the additional columns of information).  As my brainstorming of formulas and functions dwindled, I sat back and wondered if there might be a different approach and got to thinking that this might be much easier if I simply attempted to match the longer list to the shorter list.  I then found the following post

[**Excel: Check if Cell value exists in Column, and then get the value of the NEXT Cell**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915215/excel-check-if-cell-value-exists-in-column-and-then-get-the-value-of-the-next)

in which I came across the following formula:

> =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B, 0)), "No Match", "Match")

I applied it to my problem with this formula [simplified to make it easier to read]:

> =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,'[OTHER WORKBOOK.xlsx]SHEET'!$F:$F, 0)), "No Match", "Match")

*Note that my original Column E became Column F due to the insertion of a column for other reasons.*

In the end, it came out looking like this:

[image]

Using the word "vigor" as an example, what this sheet now tells me is that "vigor" matches a word on another list, but not on the list I am currently studying (because Column J contains "No Match") and that it meets two other criteria I have established.  I don't know if this type of solution can work in every instance, but it works for my purposes here, and if you are reading this, perhaps it is a solution that works for you as well.

---

I'll hold off on giving myself the green checkmark in case someone knows how to solve this the way I had originally envisioned, or has a better solution altogether.  So if you've been working on a solution to this or just now want to take it on, and can come up with something you think would be helpful, don't hesitate to post your answer as well.